# Showing Hierarchy / Project view during UV editing

Tags: uv-image-editor

When I switch from "Default" to "UV Editing", the "View" pane on the right always disappears.

[image]

Is this intended for some reason, and if yes, for which reason?
Can I simply show it again? I haven't found any key combination for it yet.

Thank you.

Comment: You can re-arrange workspace layout areas at anytime. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html

Comment: That is intended behavior. The default UV Layout is set to have no outiner visible. As Carlo mentioned you can personalize it at will and save it in the default startup file.

Comment: But there is no easy shortcut to make the view visible again, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's UI allows us to split the window into multiple sections, each using a different [editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/index.html). These window layouts are saved as a list of [Screens](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/screens.html) which we can switch between and add to. The default UV editing screen does not provide an [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html), or a graph editor or a properties editor or dopesheet...

There are three places that screens can be defined, the default screens programmed into blender, the startup blend that has your settings or each blend file that you use. When you open a blend file there is a [Load UI](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/open.html#options) option which decides if you want to use the screens in the file you are opening or keep the screens you are currently using. You can set the default for this option in the [preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/file.html#save-load).

Every time you adjust the window layout you are altering the current screen and that adjustment is kept in the current screen and saved with the blend file. If you don't like the default screens that blender provides you can define your own screen layouts.

You define custom layouts by starting blender, create and adjust as many screens as you want and then [save your startup blend](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/startup_file.html). This makes them available every time you start blender, if you also disable the Load UI option in preferences and save that you will use your layouts unless you choose to use the layouts in the file as you open it.